# IOS app UIWebView or Navigation Controller

Tags: iphone, ios, uinavigationcontroller

I'm starting developing apps on iPhone, and I was wondering if you helping me with this.

**Instagram App**, **Foursquare App** both uses Navigation Buttons Bar at the bottom? Or is just a fancy navigation bar made in CSS and everything is loaded as a html in UIWebView.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be as fancy as you want and doesn't mean it's not native. The out-of-the-box controls and UI we are all familiar with are not the only option, you can subclass or even create your own "tab bar" from scratch if you want to.

These apps are using native code, not HTML/CSS

Comment: Thanks @Daniel! I have a clear view now. I've found this http://m.facebook.com for this reason comes my question. Thanks again :-)

Answer (score 2):

Grab class-dump and find it out yourself!

(...most likely, these great enterprises wouldn't hire developers who dare making a 'native' iOS app using UIWebView and HTML...)